# How to change size of grid & granularity in meshc function

Tags: matlab, plot, grid, matlab-figure, mesh

Show mask by `meshc` function

```
z = [0 0 0 0;0 1 1 0;0 0 0 0];
meshc(z)
```

Output is:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Interpolation? You have only 12 datapoints, what do you expect?

Comment: @thwaywewalk Not relevant.Just for example I wrote
More data can be.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I mean the number of windows in the grid is
Similar to the Desired image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of guessing on my side, and I guess you want something like this:

```
%// data
z = [0 0 0 0;0 1 1 0;0 0 0 0];

%// grid
[n,m] = size(z);
[x,y] = ndgrid(1:n,1:m);

%// finer grid
[xq, yq] = ndgrid(linspace(1,n,100),linspace(1,m,100));

%// interpolation
F = griddedInterpolant(x, y, z, 'cubic')
zq = F(xq, yq);

%// interpolated plot
figure(1)
meshc(xq,yq,zq)
```

---

[image]